# How to add data from submitted form fields to EXM message template

Tags: sitecore-client, exm

Sitecore.NET 9.0.2, EXM

Hi there, I am using the Sitecore Forms Extension module (https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions) to allow my client to add file attachments to forms on their site. However as part of this they want to be able to send emails with these files as attachments, which is fine as the module extends the Send Email save action to allow this.

However, they also wish to include the values submitted to various form fields - such as name and contact details - within the body of the message. It seems that EXM only has the ability to include values about known users into email bodies, and, of course, has no knowledge of what is available as data from the form because I cannot attach the campaign to the form until after I have activated it, and thus locked it for future editing.

Has anyone tried to do something similar and can EXM be made to recognise that the form that is triggering the email send has data that can be populated into the message body?

Comment: Hi Adam, you can also find this in the documentation of the module. http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/sitecoreformsextentions/contenteditordoc/sendmail/exm.html#using-form-values-in-the-email

Comment: Thanks Bart, I misssed this when reviewing the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module you are using already has that option.

> Create an automated message in EXM. You can use the token `$formFields$`
>   to render the entire form results or use `$form_fieldName$` to add the
>   fields individually